# Android unit test using instrumentation without Activity

Tags: android, unit-testing, instrumentation

I want to unit test some Android code in isolation from an Activity. The code does some Bitmap processing. I already tried Robolectric and it appears the Bitmap it returns is some sort of facade and does not contain real pixel values so Robolectric is out of the question. I want to isolate the code that does the processing from the rest of the system. I've tried `ActivityUnitTestCase` with an Activity I create in my test class, but the test fails at `startActivity(intent, null, null);` I'm assuming this is because the Activity is not part of the application (not listed in the manifest).

How can I run a piece of Android code, instrumented, without an Activity?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Just use [InstrumentationTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html).